# What should we do with these questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

We've had some discussion about what to do with old questions that are no longer on-topic here. We aren't getting a clear consensus, so maybe it'd be simpler to talk about actual questions rather than generalities.

Let's use the answers here to post actual, old questions, along with a suggested action. Voting up means people agree with the proposal, voting down means disagreement.

If you disagree, let's why discuss in the comments.

Comment: Ooooh. Great way to handle this :)

Comment: From my very humble point of view the very important stuff to do is to wonder: Why do I feel that it's important to close a question. Which are the pro in doing it. Every human being should cope with self confirmation bias and rationalization (some defensive strategy of our mind for trying to preserve our self esteem, which goes to justify our beliefs and actions). If you want really to grow as a person, have a look to them on wikipedia. ps: I'm not better than you or anyone else. Just trying to study..

Answer (score 7):

**[Urban erotica and authors](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/urban-erotica-and-authors)**

Asking for literature recommendations.

Suggested action: **Close** as off-topic

*Edit: Closed.*

Answer (score 3):

**[What helpful writing exercises do you use?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/345/what-helpful-writing-exercises-do-you-use)**

This question is really an attempt at discussion. While maybe it could have become a more concrete question, the answers are very random and there's no way to choose a canonical answer.

Suggested action: **Close**

Comment: Should definitely be closed, but I think we can give this one a historical lock.

Comment: Yes, close with historical lock.

Comment: I'm opposed to the rule that questions need to allow for only one correct answer. We are not in Stackoverflow, where code either works or doesn't. People are different, and writing styles differ, so any answer can have as many correct answers as there are writers. I suggest we leave this question open and allow other users to give their own correct answer.

Comment: @what - Questions can have more that one correct answer, but there has to be a way to choose the *best* answer. List questions like this don't allow for that.

Comment: Huh? I don't see how a best exercise cannot be chosen.

Comment: Locked as per this answer.

Answer (score 3):

**[Good books on writing for comics?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/834/good-books-on-writing-for-comics)**

List questions like this are explicitly off-topic on SE sites, but we seem to have made an exception for lists of reference books here. And this information is probably useful.

Suggested actions: **Leave open** and **protect** the question.

Comment: Open + protect, or historical lock?  If this isn't the type of question we want, should we leave it open?

Comment: Counter-proposal: close but don't lock (so people can still vote for answers they find useful).  (I'm making this a separate comment so people can vote separately if they agree with either of these ideas.)

Comment: Either historical lock, if we decide we don't accept such questions, or leave it open. It isn't attracting poor answers; I don't see any reason to protect. The guideline is that [protection isn't meant to be used preemptively](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/); if the page starts drawing trash, we can protect it then.

Comment: Leave it open, but no need to protect.

Comment: I'm with Lauren on this one.

Answer (score 2):

**[What genre is this?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/908/what-genre-is-a-book-in-an-imaginary-world-but-no-other-fantasy-element)**

Unlikely to help future visitors.

Suggested action: **Close**

*OUTCOME: Was edited to be less specific to this work, and retitled as "What genre is a book in an imaginary world but no other fantasy element?"  After the edits, the consensus was to keep it.*

Comment: This question - and the issue of genre-identification questions - is discussed on http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/144/are-what-genre-is-this-questions-on-topic .

Comment: My own personal opinion is that genre-identification questions are valuable because genre navigation is difficult, and an important part of branding, querying, and self-publishing. However, these questions do tend to be highly localized.

Comment: Also,  I've edited the title to give a better indication of contents.

Answer (score 1):

[Is the opening of this story intriguing, "dark" and smooth?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/is-the-opening-of-this-story-intriguing-dark-and-smooth)

This is a request for a writing critique.  It would clearly be off-topic now, questions like this are closed all the time.  Furthermore it is frequently on the main page, so it isn't just buried, and it gives the wrong idea of what we do here.

Suggested action: **Close**

Answer (score -2):

**[Where can I find sales numbers for books?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/where-can-i-find-sales-numbers-for-books)**

Not a question that's been answered definitively, but contains potentially useful information.

Suggested action: **Historical lock**

*Edit: Consensus is to leave this be.*

Comment: I would close but not lock.  (I could be talked into a lock, but should close in any case.)

Comment: I'm conflicted. Why do you want to close/lock this? Isn't finding sales numbers a common task for writers? I could see closing this as a "recommend me a service" question, but to me it feels more like "how do I go about performing [difficult, poorly-documented task]".

Comment: Leave open. This question still wants a useful answer, but the question itself is one of the more generally useful ones.